# Optimizing A Slow Search Multi-Join Oracle SQL Query Hibernate for High Volume Data?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, optimization, query-optimization

First of all we have looked through several questions and documentations related to query-optimization that might help in addressing this scenario, but we are still unclear nor uncertain of what could be the problem.

We are currently trying to look for the best way to improve the query search method with Hibernate that is slowing down when there's a heavy volume of records involved in child tables. The method involved has SQL called at least four times with:

- a) A list searching for identity cards (borrowers) within the
  selected paymaster and a processing either before the starting date
  or after the ending date. (This is acceptable as it is a single table
  search)

  b) Searching for a list of active bookings (canceled, new, validated,
  but not rejected or settled) based on the list of borrowers above

  c) Searching for a list of stopped bookings but are still active and
  processed based on the list of borrowers above.

Note: we use a IN as a condition if there are less than 1000 borrowers, otherwise, we use a OR IN condition.

The results from B and C (they are in one single function) are combined into another entity List as CA.

d) Each entity in the CA list is subjected to a call amount generation function before being processed into a file.

If there is more than one paymaster selected, then they cycle from A-D will start again with the next paymaster.

Four main tables involved in the processes above with fetch mode Join used for the sub tables:
LoanFacility (main table)
Call Amount (sub-table)
Deduction Code (sub-table monthly deductions for the active borrowers)
Payment (sub-table monthly payments made for the active borrowers)

Borrower (side table used for B and C)

The method that is doing B and C is as below:

```
Criteria rootCriteria = session.createCriteria(LoanFacility.class);
rootCriteria.createAlias("fiBorrower", "fiBorrower");
setFetchModeForSubmissionFiles(rootCriteria);
rootCriteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);


//the work around for cases where there are more than 1000 borrowers
rootCriteria.add(QueryHelper.buildSplitCriterion("fiBorrower.icNumber",borrowerIcs.subList(first, max)));

            Conjunction andClause1 = Restrictions.conjunction();

            // we use statusForSubmission instead of submissionStatus because we
            // need to check previous status
            List<Integer> statusForSubmission = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            <Statuses from valid, processed, cancelled, etc..> excluding new, rejected and settled are added here>
            andClause1.add(Restrictions.in("status", statusForSubmission));

            if (processingDate != null) {
                Date endDate = DateUtil.getLastDate(processingDate);
                andClause1.add(Restrictions.le("commencementMonth", endDate));

                Conjunction andClause2 = Restrictions.conjunction();

                andClause2.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("reactivateCommencementDate"));
                andClause2.add(Restrictions.le("reactivateCommencementDate", endDate));

                rootCriteria.add(Restrictions.or(andClause1, andClause2));

            } else {
                rootCriteria.add(Restrictions.and(andClause1));
            }

            List<LoanFacility> allLoanFacilities = rootCriteria.list();
            for (LoanFacility loanfacility : allLoanFacilities) {
                LOG.info("Booking with ID in ori list: " + loanfacility.getBookingId());
                if (loanfacility.getStatus() == Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_PROCESSED
                        || loanfacility.getStatus() == Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_VALIDATED
                        || (loanfacility.getPreviousStatus() != null && loanfacility.getPreviousStatus().equals(Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_PROCESSED))
                        || (loanfacility.getPreviousStatus() != null && loanfacility.getPreviousStatus().equals(Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_VALIDATED) && loanfacility
                                .getStatus() != (Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_CANCELLED))
                        || (loanfacility.getPreviousBookingStatusLog() != null && StringUtils.contains(loanfacility.getPreviousBookingStatusLog(),
                                Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_PROCESSED.toString()))
                        || (loanfacility.getPreviousBookingStatusLog() != null
                                && StringUtils.contains(loanfacility.getPreviousBookingStatusLog(), Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_VALIDATED.toString()) && loanfacility
                                .getStatus() != (Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_CANCELLED))) {
                    loanFacilities.add(loanfacility);
                    LOG.info("Booking with ID added from ori list: " + loanfacility.getBookingId());

                }
            }
```

The below is for stopped bookings that have are still process and active:

```
Criteria stoppedBookingCriteria = session.createCriteria(LoanFacility.class);
                setFetchModeForSubmissionFiles(stoppedBookingCriteria);
                stoppedBookingCriteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

                stoppedBookingCriteria.createAlias("fiBorrower", "fiBorrower");
                //include booking where the stop date in the current processing month and status already settled
                List<Integer> statusForQueryStopBooking = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                Conjunction stopBookingAndClause1 = Restrictions.conjunction();
                Conjunction stopBookingAndClause2 = Restrictions.conjunction();
                stopBookingAndClause1.add(Restrictions.eq("status",Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_PROCESSED));
                stopBookingAndClause1.add(Restrictions.between("stoppedDate", DateUtil.getFirstDate(processingDate),
                        DateUtil.getLastDate(processingDate)));

                stopBookingAndClause2.add(Restrictions.eq("status",Constants.STATUS_BOOKING_SETTLED));
                stopBookingAndClause2.add(Restrictions.between("modifiedTime", DateUtil.getFirstDate(processingDate),
                        DateUtil.getLastDate(processingDate)));

                stoppedBookingCriteria.add(Restrictions.or(stopBookingAndClause1, stopBookingAndClause2));
                stoppedBookingCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("activated", true));

                stoppedBookingCriteria.add(Restrictions.le("commencementMonth", DateUtil.getFirstDate(processingDate)));

                Criterion criterion = QueryHelper.buildSplitCriterion("fiBorrower.icNumber", borrowerIcs);
                stoppedBookingCriteria.add(criterion);
                List<LoanFacility> stoppedBookings = stoppedBookingCriteria.list();
```

On the main entity object, the child / sub objects are mapped as:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = DeductionCode.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "facility_id", updatable = false)
    public Set<DeductionCode> getDeductionCodes() {
        return deductionCodes;
    }

 @OneToMany(targetEntity = FixedAllowance.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "loan_facility_id", updatable = false)
    @NotAudited
    public Set<FixedAllowance> getFixedAllowances() {
        return fixedAllowances;
    }

@OneToMany(targetEntity = CallAmount.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "loanfacility_id", updatable = false)
    @NotAudited
    public Set<CallAmount> getCallAmounts() {
        return callAmounts;
    }
```

We have done some timings on those records. A paymaster that has 120+ bookings or about 7500+ payment and deduction records took between 35-40 minutes of processing, while a paymaster that has about 1700+ records would take about 8 minutes (one-fifth of the paymaster with the most bookings). A 300+ payment and deduction records would be about 2-3 minutes. Our goal is to have the time taken reduced by about 30%. I usually abort if they are above the average time taken with an additional 5-minute buffer.

As said, there wasn't a solution that I've looked around that might match this scenario so, in advance would appreciate if there's hints or suggestions that can be helped to improve this SQL block's performance.

**UPDATE 1**

Per @Cyril's to view, this is the Hibernate query extracted from the console. Condition wise, I've taken it from the Criterion print string.

```
select <fields from objects like Loan Facility, Call Account, Payment, etc>
            from
        LOAN_FACILITY this_ 
    left outer join
        APP_USER user3_ 
            on this_.assign_user=user3_.id 
    left outer join
        user_role roles4_ 
            on user3_.id=roles4_.user_id 
    left outer join
        ROLE role5_ 
            on roles4_.role_id=role5_.id 
    left outer join
        DEDUCTION_CODE deductionc6_ 
            on this_.id=deductionc6_.facility_id 
    left outer join
        LOAN_FACILITY loanfacili7_ 
            on deductionc6_.FACILITY_ID=loanfacili7_.id 
    left outer join
        FI_BORROWER fiborrower8_ 
            on loanfacili7_.fi_borrower_id=fiborrower8_.id 
    left outer join
        FINANCIAL_INSTITUTION financiali9_ 
            on fiborrower8_.fi_id=financiali9_.id 
    left outer join
        BANK bank10_ 
            on financiali9_.bank_id=bank10_.id 
    left outer join
        FI_TYPE fitype11_ 
            on financiali9_.FITYPE_CODE=fitype11_.code 
    left outer join
        FI_CLASSIFICATION ficlassifi12_ 
            on fitype11_.classification_code=ficlassifi12_.code 
    left outer join
        FINANCIAL_INSTITUTION financiali13_ 
            on financiali9_.parentFI_id=financiali13_.id 
    left outer join
        BANK bank14_ 
            on financiali13_.secondaryBank_id=bank14_.id 
    left outer join
        OCCUPATION occupation15_ 
            on fiborrower8_.occupation_id=occupation15_.id 
    left outer join
        OCCUPATION_CLASSIFICATION occupation16_ 
            on occupation15_.classification_id=occupation16_.id 
    left outer join
        FIXED_ALLOWANCE fixedallow17_ 
            on loanfacili7_.id=fixedallow17_.loan_facility_id 
    inner join
        FI_BORROWER fiborrower1_ 
            on this_.fi_borrower_id=fiborrower1_.id 
    where
        fiBorrower.icNumber in (<all the Id numbers here) or fiBorrower.icNumber in (850928146543), (status in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10) and commencementMonth <=Tue Oct 31 23:59:59 SGT 2017) or (reactivateCommencementDate is not null and reactivateCommencementDate <=Tue Oct 31 23:59:59 SGT 2017)])
```

UPDATE 2:
The statistics isn't showing any significance. On that function, it merely shows the following:

```
Logging statistics....
Logging statistics....
Start time: 1508162337450
Start time: 1508162337450
Sessions opened: 0
Sessions closed: 0
Transactions: 0
Successful transactions: 0
Optimistic lock failures: 0
Flushes: 0
Connections obtained: 0
Statements prepared: 0
Statements closed: 0
Second level cache puts: 0
Second level cache hits: 0
Second level cache misses: 0
Entities loaded: 0
Entities updated: 0
Entities inserted: 0
Entities deleted: 0
Entities fetched (minimize this): 0
Collections loaded: 0
Collections updated: 0
Collections removed: 0
Collections recreated: 0
Collections fetched (minimize this): 0
NaturalId cache puts: 0
NaturalId cache hits: 0
NaturalId cache misses: 0
Max NaturalId query time: 0ms
NaturalId queries executed to database: 0
Queries executed to database: 0
Query cache puts: 0
update timestamps cache puts: 0
update timestamps cache hits: 0
update timestamps cache misses: 0
Query cache hits: 0
Query cache misses: 0
Max query time: 0ms
```

Comment: Do you run this query very often? do you need real time data for this query or can you afford to have an approximate result?
Can you show the query and the execution plan?
This is most likely a SQL tuning task, so you need to provide enough information to help you with that.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO The update above is the extract from the Hibernate query that is taken from the console appender. This query is usually run on a monthly basis (usually within the first 8 days of the month). A requirement that is much a headache is that they want to have the list of bookings since from day 1 the borrower gets his / her loan.

Comment: Can you also post the execution plan?

Comment: Sorry, was held up by other things. The stat above was for that particular sub-function. In the meanwhile, I've indexed the filtering columns (commencement month, recommencement date), increased the max elements in memory (ehcache) and setting a fetchsize of up to 200 for that function. 
What I suspected is the logic behind the function. Too broad in strokes.